# Generic Makefile Pattern to compile every source to corresponding object file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, rule

Hi i m trying to use a generic makefile to build my project.

The error i get is that duplicate functions exist in my sourcecode. I checked with nm and yes they are there. I know i could write a normale makefile with every sourcefile named explicitly and compiled line by line. But the nature of my project demands, that others are able to integrate new plattforms without and port the whole affair to new machines. (Which means in the long run, even the direct library paths will have to become relative)
Any help appreciated.

Additional Information:
The Host system is windows 7, i compile using MinGW 32 (nuwens distro) - and as crosscompiler and library provider i use gnu-arm-none-eabi-gcc from the ARM-Launchpad.

```
#PATHS

GEN_SOURCE_PATH=    ../../source/generate_osek
HW_SOURCE_PATH=     $(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)/$(PLATFORM)_hw/
ASM_PATH=           $(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)/$(PLATFORM)_hw/$(PLATFORM)_asm
HEADER_PATH=        $(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)/header


#HEADERS
ORG_HEADERS =   $(HEADER_PATH)/
HW_HEADERS  =   $(HEADER_PATH)/$(PLATFORM)_head/
ALL_HEADERS =   $(ORG_HEADERS) $(HW_HEADERS)

INCLUDES =      -I/c/osek/workspace/htosek/source/generate_osek/header/
INCLUDES +=     -I/c/osek/workspace/htosek/source/generate_osek/header/$(PLATFORM)_head/
INCLUDES +=     -I/c/osek/workspace/htosek/source/$(PLATFORM)_hw/
INCLUDES +=     -I/c/osek/workspace/htosek/source/
INCLUDES +=     -I/c/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/include/
#Library
LIBS = -L/c/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/  -lgcc


#LISTSOURCES
ASM_INCLUDE= -I$(ASM_PATH)/   


#SOURCEFILES
CFILES      =   $(foreach dir,$(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)/,$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
CFILES      +=  $(foreach dir,$(HW_SOURCE_PATH),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
SFILES      =   $(foreach dir,$(ASM_PATH)/,$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.s)))
HFILES      =   $(foreach dir,$(ORG_HEADERS),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.h)))
HFILES      +=  $(foreach dir,$(HW_HEADERS),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.h)))

#VPATH
VPATH= $(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)
VPATH+= $(ASM_PATH)
VPATH+= $(ALL_HEADERS)

#DEPENDENCIES
DEP = $(subst .o,.d,$(SOBJS) $(COBJS))
#Converting

SOBJS  =    $(SFILES:.s=.o)
COBJS   =   $(CFILES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS =  $(COBJS) $(SOBJS) 
#WARNINGS= -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Werror -Wno-unused
LOCAL_CFLAG= -v -d -c    -ffreestanding
C_FLAGS += $(LOCAL_CFLAG)

#GENERATE_OSEK BINARY
os: bin
    @echo "Generating binary image file: $@"
    $(OBJCOPY_DEVICE) -O binary $(EXEC) $@

#LINKING OBJECTS
bin:$(OBJECTS)  
    @echo ""
    @echo "Linking $<..." 
    $(LD_DEVICE) -o $(EXEC)  $(OBJECTS)  $(LD_FLAGS) $(LIBS)
    @echo ""
    @echo "And done..."

#COMPILING ASSEMBLY
$(SOBJS):  $(SFILES)
    @echo ""
    @echo "Assembling $<..."
    $(ASM_DEVICE)  $(ASM_INCLUDE)  $(ASM_FLAGS) -g -v  -o $@   $^ 

#COMPILING C SOURCES
$(COBJS): $(CFILES) ${HFILES}
    @echo ""
    @echo Compiling $<...
    $(CC_DEVICE) $(C_FLAGS)  $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS)  -g  -o $@  $^

os_clean:
     RM *.o 
     RM $(EXEC)
```

Update:
I added some missing includes to the VPATH and now at least it compiles to the error stated in the beginning:

Updated Makefile:
    #PATHS

```
GEN_SOURCE_PATH=    ../../source/generate_osek
HW_SOURCE_PATH=     $(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)/$(PLATFORM)_hw/
ASM_PATH=           $(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)/$(PLATFORM)_hw/$(PLATFORM)_asm
HEADER_PATH=        $(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)/header


#HEADERS
ORG_HEADERS =   $(HEADER_PATH)/
HW_HEADERS  =   $(HEADER_PATH)/$(PLATFORM)_head/
ALL_HEADERS =   $(ORG_HEADERS) $(HW_HEADERS)

INCLUDES =      -I/c/osek/workspace/htosek/source/generate_osek/header/
INCLUDES +=     -I/c/osek/workspace/htosek/source/generate_osek/header/$(PLATFORM)_head/
INCLUDES +=     -I/c/osek/workspace/htosek/source/
INCLUDES +=     -I/c/osek/workspace/htosek/source/$(PLATFORM)_hw/
INCLUDES +=     -I/c/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/include/
#Library
LIBS = -L/c/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/  -lgcc


#LISTSOURCES
ASM_INCLUDE= -I$(ASM_PATH)/   


#SOURCEFILES
CFILES      =   $(foreach dir,$(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)/,$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
CFILES      +=  $(foreach dir,$(HW_SOURCE_PATH),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
SFILES      =   $(foreach dir,$(ASM_PATH)/,$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.s)))
HFILES      =   $(foreach dir,$(ORG_HEADERS),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.h)))
HFILES      +=  $(foreach dir,$(HW_HEADERS),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.h)))

#VPATH
VPATH= $(GEN_SOURCE_PATH)/
VPATH += $(HW_SOURCE_PATH)
VPATH+= $(ASM_PATH)
VPATH+= $(ALL_HEADERS)

#DEPENDENCIES
DEP = $(subst .o,.d,$(SOBJS) $(COBJS))
#Converting

SOBJS  =    $(SFILES:.s=.o)
COBJS   =   $(CFILES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS =  $(COBJS) $(SOBJS) 
#WARNINGS= -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Werror -Wno-unused
LOCAL_CFLAG= -v -d -c    -ffreestanding
C_FLAGS += $(LOCAL_CFLAG)

#GENERATE_OSEK BINARY
os: bin
    @echo "Generating binary image file: $@"
    $(OBJCOPY_DEVICE) -o binary $(EXEC) $@

#LINKING OBJECTS
bin:$(OBJECTS)  
    @echo ""
    @echo "Linking $<..." 
    $(LD_DEVICE) -o $(EXEC)  $(OBJECTS)  $(LD_FLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@
    @echo ""
    @echo "And done..."

#COMPILING ASSEMBLY
$(SOBJS):  $(SFILES)
    @echo ""
    @echo "Assembling $<..."
    $(ASM_DEVICE)  $(ASM_INCLUDE)  $(ASM_FLAGS) -g -v  -o $@   $^ 

#COMPILING C SOURCES
$(COBJS): $(CFILES) ${HFILES}
    @echo ""
    @echo "Compiling: $< -> $@"
    $(CC_DEVICE) $(C_FLAGS)  $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS)  -g  -o $@ $^

os_clean:
     RM *.o 
     RM $(EXEC) 
     RM *.gch
```

**Updated Error Sample:**

```
debug_hook.o: In function `resetAlarm':
c:\osek\workspace\htosek\project\test/../../source/generate_osek/alarm.c:19: multiple definition of `resetAlarm'
alarm.o:c:\osek\workspace\htosek\project\test/../../source/generate_osek/alarm.c:19: first defined here
debug_hook.o: In function `RaiseAlarm':
c:\osek\workspace\htosek\project\test/../../source/generate_osek/alarm.c:25: multiple definition of `RaiseAlarm'
alarm.o:c:\osek\workspace\htosek\project\test/../../source/generate_osek/alarm.c:25: first defined here
debug_hook.o: In function `TimeTillAlarm':
c:\osek\workspace\htosek\project\test/../../source/generate_osek/alarm.c:54: multiple definition of `TimeTillAlarm'
alarm.o:c:\osek\workspace\htosek\project\test/../../source/generate_osek/alarm.c:54: first defined here
make: *** [bin] Error 1
```

TimeTillAlarm exists definatly just once. No Predeclarations elsewhere. Greped for it over the whole source.

Linker Script:

arm-none-eabi-ld  -o test.elf alarm.o debug_hook.o fifo_array.o      fifo_queue.o htosek_startup.o i_basic_op_abstraction.o     i_driver_op_abstraction.o othsek.o task.o at91sam72s256_restarttask.o     at91sam72s256_startup.o at91sam72s256_system.o __irfunctions.o     _activatetask.o _contextswitch.o _cstartup.o _ir_vector_table.o       _restartTask.o  -M -nostartfiles -nostdlib -L/c/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/  -lgcc'

**Update:**
nm shows that all assembler o.files have the same symbol

```
P@P-PC /c/osek/workspace/htosek/project/test
$ nm debug_hook.o
00000084 t $a
00000000 t $a
00000010 N $d
00000080 t $d
0000047c C HTOsek
00000098 T InitAlarm
0000000c T RaiseAlarm
00000000 T resetAlarm
00000084 T TimeTillAlarm

P@P-PC /c/osek/workspace/htosek/project/test
$ nm fifo_array.o
00000084 t $a
00000000 t $a
00000010 N $d
00000080 t $d
0000047c C HTOsek
00000098 T InitAlarm
0000000c T RaiseAlarm
00000000 T resetAlarm
00000084 T TimeTillAlarm
```

o.files from c_sources seem to be in the same shape, but have at least a diffrent set of symbols. 
**Conclusion:** One sourcefile is made into diffent named o.files for both groups. Anyone Suggestions to why?

Thanks again for the patience and advice

Comment: It might be helpful to people looking at this if you paste the whole command line being run when performing the linking for the case you get duplicate symbols. Are you also 100% sure there are no real duplicate symbols in all the source files you're compiling and linking together ?

Comment: Here is the linker script line: 
arm-none-eabi-ld   -o test.elf  ..all the o.files.. LD_FLAGS =     -M -nostartfiles -nostdlib -L/c/gnuarm/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/  -lgcc 
PS: I check with make print-CFILES
and some of them where missing. So i added the Folder and it seems my CFILE buildrule is also faulty.
Will update my original post.
make: *** No rule to make target `at91sam72s256_restarttask.c', needed by `alarm.o'.  Stop.

Comment: You have to show us the actual command line. Copy paste the whole line. Everything. The interesting part is among other things the " ..all the o.files.." that you left out, and update your question with that info instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: As a side note, the line `$(CC_DEVICE) $(C_FLAGS)  $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS)  -g  -o $@ $^` should be written as `$(CC_DEVICE) $(C_FLAGS)  $(INCLUDES)  -g  -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)`.